# Is this number theoretic quantity bounded above?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, prime-numbers, inequalities, asymptotics

I  am considering a combinatorial argument which involves the following quantity.  We use the prime counting function $\pi(n)$ and to save on exponents we set $h=\pi(n/2)$.  The quantity as a function of integer  $n \gt 7$ is
$$(\pi(n)!)^{1/(n-h)}$$

Computations for small $n$ suggest this is always less than $4$, as do rough back-of-the-envelope asymptotic calculations.  Is this bounded above for all $n \gt 7$?  If so, what is the bound? (I'm hoping it is always less than 3.)

Gerhard "Researching Minds Want To Know" Paseman, 2020.05.30.

Comment: nice question ,upvote

Comment: I think it is upper bounded by 4 using a rough approximation to the prime counting function. I would appreciate verification.  Gerhard "Worth An Acknowledgement To Me" Paseman, 2020.05.30.

Comment: Don't you just want to plug an effective form of the prime number theorem into Stirling's formula here?

Comment: Your rough back-of-the-envelope asymptotic calculations suggest the limit is $e$, right? I think these calculations, unless you did them in a very strange way, are already a proof.

Comment: I often do strange things @Will. I guess I am just looking for confirmation. Gerhard "Anything For These Uncertain Times" Paseman, 2020.05.30.

Comment: And the rough calculations suggest something greater than $e$, while the numerical computations suggest something less than $e$.  If I can tweak the argument to get a related quantity less than 2, I am within spitting distance of combinatorial proof of. a theorem  of Sylvester. Gerhard "More Combinatorial Than Sylvester's Proof" Paseman, 2020.05.30.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $k:=\pi(n)$, so that $p_k\le n<p_{k+1}$, where $p_k$ is the $k$th prime. By the last displayed formula in [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number) of the Wikipedia article, 
\begin{equation*}
 -1+\ln(k\ln k)<\frac{p_k}k<\ln(k\ln k)
\end{equation*}
if $k\ge6$, whence 
\begin{equation*}
 n>-k+k\ln(k\ln k),\quad n/2<m_k:=\frac{k+1}2\,\ln((k+1)\ln(k+1)).
\end{equation*}
Therefore, letting 
\begin{equation*}
 c_1:=1.25506,\quad r(k):=\frac{\ln((k+1)\ln(k+1))}{\ln m_k} 
\end{equation*}
and using [this result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Inequalities), we get
\begin{equation*}
 h=\pi(n/2)\le\pi(m_k)<c_1\frac{m_k}{\ln m_k}=c_1\frac{k+1}2\,r(k).  
\end{equation*}
Next,
\begin{multline*}
 r(k):=\frac{\ln(k+1)+\ln\ln(k+1)}{\ln(k+1)+\ln[\ln(k+1)+\ln\ln(k+1)]-\ln2} \\ 
 <\frac{\ln(k+1)+\ln\ln(k+1)}{\ln(k+1)+\ln\ln(k+1)-\ln2}<\frac{10}9
\end{multline*}
if 
\begin{equation*}
 k\ge195,
\end{equation*}
which will be assumed henceforth.
So,\begin{equation*}
 h<c_2(k+1),
\end{equation*}
where 
\begin{equation*}
 c_2:=\frac7{10}>c_1\frac{10}9\Big/2. 
\end{equation*}
So, using the trivial inequality $k!\le k^k$, we have
\begin{equation*}
\ln[(\pi(n)!)^{1/(n-h)}]=\frac{\ln(k!)}{n-h}
\le\frac{k\ln k}{-k+k\ln(k\ln k)-c_2(k+1)}
<\frac{k\ln k}{k\ln k}=1
\end{equation*}
and hence 
\begin{equation*}
 (\pi(n)!)^{1/(n-h)}<e \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
for $k\ge239$, that is, for $n\ge1499$. By direct calculation, (1) holds for $n\le1498$ as well. 
It is also easy to see that the upper bound $e$ on $(\pi(n)!)^{1/(n-h)}$ is exact.

Comment: Thanks for this! I will go over this and cite it in my write-up.  It turns out I have some leeway: h can be a little larger than pi(n/2), and it is enough if I can show a weaker upper bound of three minus epsilon or even four minus epsilon.  Do you think we can simplify this given the leeway, but also arrange so that it holds for k greater than 50, so that less computation for small k is needed?  (I'm willing to accept verifying k less than 40, so that c1 can drop a bit.) Gerhard "Looking Forward To The Math" Paseman, 2020.05.31.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman : If you make $h$ larger, then your expression will get larger. However, if you don't need the exact upper bound, then the increase of $h$ could be OK within certain limits, and even the proof could possibly be simplified. I suspect the proof can be simplified a bit anyway, as many of the first proofs.

Comment: I have indeed simplified the proof a bit.

Comment: Thank you again. I will upvote and accept this later.  It turns out I have a simpler argument and simpler quantity to estimate which achieves my goal.  I will post later after I have checked it .  Gerhard "Can it Be So Simple?" Paseman, 2020.05.31.

Comment: I have further simplified the answer, which now does not use any version of Stirling's formula.

Answer (score 1):

So I accept the answer of Iosif Pinelis, but it turns out I don't need the exact result now.  I will post some backstory, and then the reason I don't need it now.

Thanks to MathOverflow user Daniel.W, and his question (360323) on strengthening Sylvester's theorem, I've been motivated to read the paper On Arithmetical Series. I approached it after a hint from Emil Jerabek to look at the thesis of Alan Woods. The thesis contained a write-up of Sylvester's method that I finally understood, and this allowed me to try to understand some of the proof in the 1892 paper.

A different version appears in a 1929 paper of Schur (which I have yet to find) and a (mostly) combinatorial one in a paper of Erdos in 1934.  However, the arguments are still involved, and the Erdos paper leaves a lot of finitely many exceptions to be explored to yield a full proof.

After looking at the basic relation in Sylvester's paper, I  (re-)discovered a result that allowed one to show that there was a number in (m,m+,n] with a prime factor greater than n whenever 4m was at least as big as n^2. This was heartening since  previously I could only show it for m bigger than exponential in n. This in turn allowed me to discover a method which involved the quantity  in the question above, and simple arguments showed that m only needed to be bigger than a small constant times n. (Iosif's argument and some additional computation shows the small constant is 3.).  I then was going to attempt a third method to bridge the remaining gap which is for all m at least n.  All of this was then going to be retooled to answer the motivating MathOverflow question.

After seeing Iosif's argument and thinking on simplifying the motivating argument, I found it.  Here it is.

Write the product of the integers in (m,m+n] as P=(m+1)...(m+n).  Rewrite as W(n!)L, where W are the prime factors of P/(n!) which are at most n gathered together, and L is the product of all the prime factors larger than n.

A key observation of Sylvester, (which I invite the reader to prove) is that W is at most (and for n bigger than 7, strictly less than) (m+n-p+1)...(m+n), where p is $\pi(n)$. This is because W is the product of p distinct prime powers, each one dividing a term of P (and usually different powers divide different terms, we suffer no loss in assuming this).

So if (m,m+n] has only n-smooth numbers, then L=1 and n! Is bigger (not necessarily strictly) than (m+1)...(m+n-p).  The literature now expends a lot of effort to show how small m is, and Sylvester himself resorts to existence of primes in (m, 3m/2] to complete his argument.  There is an easier way, however.

Write m=jn+i for i non negative. Then rewrite W(n!) = P by dividing out W and dividing out terms in the factorial larger than p.  We get p! greater than j^(n-p), if P is n-smooth.

But we can argue with Chebyshev estimates to get j less than 6, and if we are as thorough as Iosif we can get j less than 3 with a small amount of computation needed. I need to perform this step but I believe p less than 50 should be more than sufficient.

So when the dust settles, we have reduced a large portion of Sylvester's argument to showing log(p!) Is less than n-p, using nothing more than grade school arithmetic and Sylvester's observation on W. With care we get that (m,m+n] has a multiple of a prime greater than n when m is at least 3n or greater.  If need be, we can turn to the Erdos proof to handle m smaller than 3n.

However, there is more. The motivating question asks for two distinct numbers in the interval which have prime factors bigger than n.  We now let L be a product of d many candidates for fixed d of members of (m,m+n]. We now are comparing log(p!) to  n-p-d, and we will get the same bound on j, although this bound may start holding for larger m only.

Given the amount of time I spent reading these proofs, I'm surprised not to find this observation (that j is less than 3) is in the literature.  We can use this observation, Chebyshev estimates, and work of Nagura or earlier to answer the motivating question affirmatively.  That C=18 for two numbers hasn't been proved yet.

Gerhard "Is Confident It Will Be" Paseman, 2020.05.31.

Comment: Now, seeing Iosif's replacement, of p^p. the argument has become simpler.  Gerhard "Many Thanks Again, Iosif Pinelis" Paseman, 2020.05.31.

Answer (score 0):

It seems my thinking gets organized after posting the question.

The natural logarithm of the quantity $\pi(n)!$ is near $\pi(n)\log(\pi(n)/e)  + (\log(\tau\pi(n)))/2$ (a number-theoretic use for $\tau$, the circumference of a unit radius circle). Using an approximation to $\pi(n)$ we get that this is less than $An$ for some $A \lt 2$. But $An/(n-h)$ is bounded above by $2A$, and gets very close to $A$.  So with some work the original quantity should be shown to be less than $e^A$.

Verification is still appreciated.

Gerhard "And Still Worth An Acknowledgement" Paseman, 2020.05.30.

Comment: It may help to set $k= \pi(n)$ and use upper bounds for the $n$th prime to deduce $n> k \log k+ k \log \log k - k$ because then the numerator and denominator of the logarithm will look quite similar although $\pi(n/2)$ then becomes annoying

Comment: I may do that. however, the important thing for me is that $h$ is small relative to $\pi(n)$.  Gerhard "Going To Write It Up" Paseman, 2020.05.30.

Comment: For the sake of history, I compare $\pi(n)!$ to $k^{n-h}$. If $k=3$ makes that quantity too large, then the conclusion of Sylvester's Theorem follows for his $m \gt 2n$.  This also helps toward a generalization I am working on with another MathOverflow user.  Gerhard "Not Doing It For Power" Paseman, 2020.05.30.