# Is every prime greater than 5, less than the sum of the two previous primes?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Can one prove by elementary means (such as Paul Erdös' proof of Bertrand's Postulate) that every prime greater than 5 is less than the sum of the two primes immediately preceding it?

Comment: From [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2c0c/af5bbaa02dcb7eeeebc5044a9079fc21abfe.pdf), $p_{n+2}\leq \frac{3}{2}p_{n+1}\leq p_{n+1}+\frac{3}{4}p_n$.

Comment: Prof. Bernardo Recamán Santos: the answer is YES, essentially this question was the subject matter of this previous question in MO: https://mathoverflow.net/q/113840/1593

Comment: @Wojowu: El Bachraoui's result was already established by Schur in 1929, see Jose Brox's answer here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/289402/who-first-proved-the-generalization-of-bertrands-postulate-to-2n-3n-and-3n-4 .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am to elaborate a bit on how it is that the answer I left in [this previous](https://mathoverflow.net/q/113840/1593) question implies a positive answer to Mr. Recamán's question.

By elementary means (i.e., without resorting to any complex analysis), in his paper [*Mémoire sur les nombres premiers*](http://sites.mathdoc.fr/JMPA/PDF/JMPA_1852_1_17_A19_0.pdf) (Mémoires de l'Acad. Imp. Sci. de St. Pétersbourg, VII, 1850.), P. L. Chebyshev established that for any $\varepsilon >\frac{1}{5}$, there exists an $n_{\varepsilon}\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq n_{\varepsilon}$,

$$\pi((1+\varepsilon)n)−\pi(n)>0.$$

In particular, taking $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{4}$, this implies that, for every sufficiently large $k \in \mathbb{N}$, we have that

$$p_{k+2} \leq (1.25)^{2}p_{k} < 2p_{k}$$

and whence, for every sufficiently large $k \in \mathbb{N}$, it is certainly the case that

$$p_{k+2} < 2p_{k} < p_{k}+p_{k+1}.$$

By *retracing* Chebyshev's arguments it is possible to obtain an explicit version of the previous conclusion.